# Node.js JSON async parsing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous

For example I have this file data.json:

```
var data = [
  {key: "0:0:0:1", val: 25},
  {key: "0:0:0:2", val: 1},
  {key: "0:0:0:3:0", val: "n/a"},
  {key: "0:0:0:3:1", val: "n/a"},
  {key: "0:0:0:4", val: 0},
  {key: "0:0:0:5", val: 0}
];
```

And I have this map.json which I need to use when I parsing data:

```
{
  "id": "0:0:0:1",
  "type": "0:0:0:2",
  "coords": {
    "latitude": "0:0:0:3:0",
    "longitude": "0:0:0:3:1"
  },
  "unixtime": "0:0:0:4",
  "uptime": "0:0:0:5"
}
```

And the output I need is:

```
{"id":25,"type":1,"coords":"latitude":"n/a","longitude":"n/a"},"unixtime":0,"uptime":0}
```

But there's one little problem! I don't know how can I easily parse my data.json async (non-blocking, bla-bla). It's not a JSON in fact and I can't use JSON.parse() method.

Help me please. Tell me how can I make it. How can I parse that data.json?

UPD: Many thanks to dandavis! Now I can parse all files and use it as javascript objects. Now I have another question. In map.json you see "coords" object. How can I make it "coords": { "latitude": "n/a", "longitude": "n/a" } right?
Now I have this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var map = {};
var json = {};

var data = function(data, map) {
  fs.readFile(data, function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var evaluated = eval(data+";data");

    evaluated.forEach(function(object) {

      fs.readFile(map, function(err, map) {
        if (err) throw err;

        map = JSON.parse(map, function(key, value) {
          if(object.key === value) {
            console.log(key + " " + object.val);
            json[key] = object.val;
            return(key + " " + object.val);
          }
        });

      console.log(json);
      });
    });
  });
};

data('data.json', 'map.json');
```

I guess this forEach loop is blocking something. Can I make these loops in another thread or smth? Or maybe there is the suggestion I don't know to make it pretty easy and beautiful code? How can I get JSON in format I need?

Comment: Why don't you *make* your `data.json` file actual json (as its file ending already suggests)? Currently it's more like a jsonp response, or simply a `.js` script waiting to be `eval()`ed.

Comment: So, I get this file (from another devs and that devs got it from another...) and I need to make the output.

Comment: The pragmatic way to solve this issue (if you can't modify the data.json file) would be to create a new file that is valid JSON, like @Bergi suggested. Otherwise, you're going to end up writing a bunch of unnecessary logic to extract the JSON from the original file.

Comment: data=eval(fs.readFileSync("json.json")+";data") is not "a bunch of" unnecessary logic. oops; use fs.readFile instead...

Comment: With your eval thing I get data variable which is undefined.

Comment: @dandavis: Maybe it's not "a bunch of", but it's still unnecessary. A properly formatted file is a much better option.

Comment: @AlexeySlaykovsky: i just tested the code as shown in OP and my comment, and it worked fine.

Comment: @sholanozie: i agree that good input would be ideal, but OP said it's not an option, so i showed something that is an option...

Comment: @dandavis: Fair enough. It seems that your solution is the actual pragmatic way to solve the problem (!).

Comment: Yeah. The problem was in '' instead of "".

Comment: Note to the OP.  I cannot follow in all these comments what you think the question still is.  If what you are looking for help with has changed, please use the edit link to modify your posting to describe what you actually want help with.  Otherwise, the rest of us will just ignore because we can't tell what you now want help with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I did it!

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = function(dataFile, mapFile, done) {
  console.log('Function start');
  fs.readFile(dataFile, function(err, dataString) {
    if(err) return done(err);

    var evaluated = eval(dataString+";data");

    var data = evaluated.reduce(function(data, item) {
      data[item.key] = item.val;
      return data;
    }, {});

    fs.readFile(mapFile, function(err, mapString) {
      if(err) return done(err);

      var map = JSON.parse(mapString, function(key, value) {
        if(value in data) return data[value];
        return value;
      });

      return done(null, map);
    });
  });
  console.log('Function end');
};

data('data.json', 'map.json', function(err, map) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
  console.log('Function success!');
});
```

Comment: it uses JSON.parse, it is not async

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution. You can check it.

```js
var json=require('./test.json')
    _=require('underscore');

var data = [
  {key: "0:0:0:1", val: 25},
  {key: "0:0:0:2", val: 1},
  {key: "0:0:0:3:0", val: "n/a"},
  {key: "0:0:0:3:1", val: "n/a"},
  {key: "0:0:0:4", val: 0},
  {key: "0:0:0:5", val: 0}
];
data=_.indexBy(data,'key');
var match=function(json){
 for(var i in json){
  if(typeof(json[i])==='object'){
   match(json[i]);
  }else{
   for(var j in data){
    if(j === json[i]){
     json[i]=data[j].val;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
match(json);
console.log(json);
```

'test.json' is the sample json file provided.

Comment: This is not async. ;(

Answer (score -1):

What you need is finally possible in 2023:

https://github.com/mmomtchev/everything-json

If you are curious about why it was such a huge problem - I suggest you read this https://github.com/mmomtchev/everything-json/blob/main/doc/Introduction.md

Basically the problem is that V8 does not allow the creation of objects unless the code is running on the main thread which also blocks the event loop.

Simply install it:

```
npm i everything-json
```

Then in your code:

```js
import { JSON } from 'everything-json';

const document = await JSON.parseAsync(jsonText);

// get everything
const data = await data.toObjectAsync();

// get just one element (much faster)
const data = await data.get().subobject.get().subelement.get();
```

*(I am the author)*

Comment: The documentation suggests this library only handles JSON but the question is about parsing JavaScript source code.

Comment: No, it is about JSON. I added how to use it.

Comment: @mmomtchev — Have you looked at the contents of `data.json` in the question? That **isn't** JSON!